# It is possible to see the Custom B2B app in iTunes App Store?

Tags: ios, mdm, itunes-store, b2b, app-distribution

We have developed an Custom B2B app.That was uploaded into iTunesConnect and get successful review.Now,we need to use MDM (Mac OS Server App) to add user profiles for that app.If we add user profiles using MDM,will that user able to see that app in iTunes App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i came to know after so much time.For Custom B2B,We can't see that app in iTunes Store the app will be installed over the air by using MDM.The device will get alert given in below image 
[Click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge0Kt.png)
After Clicking on install button the app will automatically starts installing on device

Comment: If you consider that your problem is solved, you can accept your own answer, this will mark the question as answered. Cheers!